# How to use bootstrap-select with angular

Tags: angularjs

I would like to style my dropdowns with [bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/).
There are two dropdowns in the page. The first one has hardcoded options. The second one is bound dynamically with data from database.

The bootstrap-select is applied all well for the first one but not the second. It adds a text 'Nothing selected' and the options also are not bound.

How to fix this.

[image]

**aspx:**

```
<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/angular-1.3.16.min.js"></script>
<script src="../scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="../scripts/controllers/Ctrl.js"></script>
<script src="../scripts/services/Factory.js"></script>
<script src="../scripts/directives/directives.js"></script>

<select id="ddlReports" bootstrapselectpicker >
<option data-ng-repeat="item in Reports" value="{{item.Id}}">{{item.Name}}</option>
</select>

<select id="ddlSets" bootstrapselectpicker>
<option value="0">-- Select Question Set --</option>
<option data-ng-repeat="item in QuestionSets" value="{{item.SetId}}">{{item.Title}}</option>
</select>
```

**Ctrl.js**

```
app.controller("Ctrl", ["$scope", "Factory", function ($scope, Factory) {
 var init = function() {
 $scope.Reports = [
            { Id: 1, Name: "abc" },
            { Id: 2, Name: "def" }
        ];
  var promise = Factory.GetData();
                promise.then(function (success) {
                    if (success.data != null && success.data != '') {
                        var data = success.data;
                        $scope.QuestionSets = data.QuestionSets;
                    }                    
                },
                function (error) {                    
                });
 }
 init();
}]);
```

**directive.js**

```
app.directive('bootstrapselectpicker', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            $timeout(function () {
                element.selectpicker();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: you can use `ng-option` instead of `ng-repeat`.

Comment: And you're certain that data is returned and $scope.QuestionSets is populated with your data?

Comment: Yes. It does. Works fine when i remove 'selectpicker'.